# I don't understand the sentence structure of the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> John Kim, Sendbird’s CEO and founder, said that additional
> developments like moderation has seen a huge take-up, and services it
> plans to add into the mix include payments and logistics features, and
> that it is looking at adding in group audio conversations for
> customers to build their own Clubhouse clones.

I almost understand the meaning, but I don't get the sentence structure ... Please teach me this.

Original text is [here](https://techcrunch.com/2021/04/06/sendbird-raises-100m-at-a-1b-valuation-says-150m-users-now-interact-using-its-chat-and-video-apis/).

Comment: There is a mismatch between the subject _additional developments_ and the main verb _has_. Beyond that you'll have to make clear what it is about the structure that is confusing you.

Comment: It's simply three statements separated by commas.

Comment: It would help if you told us what you think it means. But anyway it is as @KateBunting said and is too long and convoluted and so would be betetr split up (in my humble opinion).

Comment: *services* here is a noun but could be mistaken for a verb, contributing to confusion.  Sendbird plans to add certain services to its mix (of services?).

Answer (score 0):

> John Kim, Sendbird’s CEO and founder, said that additional *developments* like moderation *has* [*sic*] seen a huge take-up, and services it plans to add into the mix include payments and logistics features, and that it is looking at adding in group audio conversations for customers to build their own Clubhouse clones. [emphasis added]

These are 3 sentences separated by coordinating conjunctions.

As what Colin has commented, in the first sentence, the verb *has* does not agree with the main subject, *developments*, and should be corrected.  The phrase *like moderation* is an appositive and should not be confused with the subject.